# 7zip to archive multiple files across many folders

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, 7-zip

I have a folder called lessons and 34 nested lessons in this folder

```
course\

 lesson1\updatedfile.html
 lesson2\updatedfile.html
 ...
 lesson34\updatedfile.html
```

The lessons folder contains just the folders for individual lessons.  The individual lesson folders contain lots of files but the only ones I want to update are all named the same thing but the updates themselves are not the same.  That is to say every updatedfile.html is different. I want to use 7zip to archive to a .zip file where the contents look like this

```
 course\lessonx(34 folders)\updatedfile.html
```

This way when I email these updates the guy can just copy and paste the main course folder over the current one and merge will handle all the specific locations.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Which OS are you using? I'm assuming Windows because of the backslash. But still, which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the following will do:

1. Open a command prompt, go to the `course` directory an execute

   ```
   "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z" a updates.zip lesson*\updatedfile.html
   ```
2. 1. Search for `updatedfile.html` in the built-in Windows search.
   2. Select all matches.
   3. Peform a right click and go through the 7-Zip dialogue.

Comment: By adding arguments for 7z you won't need to go through the dialog and can automate this process.

Comment: I found a round-about solution using portable ant renamer + cmd line "dir >file.txt" then notepadd++ to do a rectangle edit to strop down to just folder names.  Saved that as a directory.lst file and imported it into ant renamer to reanme 34 empty folders, then used windows search and drug the 34 files over.  I would like to know a fully 7zip solution that would ignore all other files.

Comment: Am I missing something? Solution `1` is pure 7zip, nothing else.

Comment: @lazfish: I included a commandline version along with some old time favorites.

Comment: I had assumed your method would not create the folder in the 7zip archive.  I don't know why.  It looks like it works great.  Also how would you proceed if instead of lesson01, lesson02 etc, your lesson folder names were completely unique?

Comment: Just omit the `lesson` part: `... updates.zip *\updatedfile.html`

Answer (score 1):

I like the above method.

1. It doesn't require remembering command line switches.
2. Creative use of Search Results
3. Noob friendly

That being said, the command line example is such:

`"%programFiles%\7-zip\7z a updates.zip updatedfile.html -r`

the `-r` tells it look through all subfolders.

**Edit:**

Old DOS tricks:

`dir` accepts two switches:

`/b` lists only the filename. Handy for outputting to a file.
`/s` lists through subfolders.

Hope that helps.